# Android: select the duration time on screen

Tags: java, android

I want to select the duration time on the screen.

I made to stay on for the time set with this code:

But I want that time can be modified from a button

```html
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

 final long MINUTES = 1000*60*2;
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            }
        };

handler.postDelayed(r, MINUTES);
```

```js
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="Time" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from EditText and store it as a SharedPreference. Then get the value and use it as duration.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String duration = mEdit.getText().toString();

SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("Test",0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("displayOnDuration", duration);
editor.commit();
```

And use this code to retrieve it:

```
SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("Test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String duration = prfs.getString("displayOnDuration", "0");

final long MINUTES = Long.parseLong(duration);
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, has been very useful, I put the code that worked for me:

```
   <EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:text="10" />
```

MainActivity

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String duration = mEdit.getText().toString();

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("Test",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("displayOnDuration", duration);
    editor.commit();
    SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("Test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    duration = prfs.getString("displayOnDuration", "3");

    final long MINUTES = 1000*60*Long.parseLong(duration);
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, MINUTES);
```

I have another question, it would be easy to keep the value of the EditText to restart the app, continue to show the same value previously entered?